# Ruby open shared memory block

Tags: ruby, shared-memory

Is there a way to open shared memory block with Ruby, equivalent to `shmop_open` in PHP?

I have one process periodically update a memory block. My Rails app needs to read those data.

Comment: Assuming you could, why would you? Seems like a case where your solution is outside the bounds of the Ruby way of solving whatever your problem is.

Comment: Our infrastructure hosts our client dbs in different servers, we used to host our client addresses in the memory whenever we boot up the server. I want to quickly access those data in the memory rather than main db query.

Comment: The typical way of handling this is environment variables, rather than arbitrary memory addresses. http://blog.honeybadger.io/ruby-guide-environment-variables/

Comment: Note: part of the issue you're going to have with this is that you'll be bypassing Ruby functionality for converting those bytes into objects. I found [this library](https://github.com/pmahoney/process_shared) but I can't imagine it's easier to jump through these hoops rather than to update your infrastructure to utilize env vars.

Comment: I also want to share those with other app running in the same server. To be clear, there is a process produced those data in the memory, I need a way to read the data in Ruby. That library looks very promising.

Comment: @coreyward Shared memory (probably combined with `String#unpack`) is a lot more powerful and flexible than environment variables. Try throwing a big chunk of data into `ENV` or modifying another process's `ENV` for simple examples.

Comment: @Ln9187 Did you look Zeromq?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options as gems, but I've never used them myself.

[sysvmq](https://github.com/Sirupsen/sysvmq) implements System V IPC message queues.

[posix-mqueues](https://github.com/Sirupsen/posix-mqueue) implements POSIX message queues.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `hammerspace`

We use this as a caching layer for translations and configurations on our production machines.

You can have one process that periodically updates the hammerspace files, and then all the rails processes can consume it. The file gets memorymapped when `hammerspace` accesses it, so it is defacto shared memory.

See https://github.com/airbnb/hammerspace