# sharing singleton between tasks in ruby thor CLI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, command-line-interface, thor

I'm implementing a ruby command line application (interactive application) and I'm using thor gem for CLI. I will have three tasks, and one of the tasks is loading the external files and storing it. The other tasks involve manipulating the file contents that was stored. I don't want to load the file everytime a task is run, it should be one time. I plan on creating a singleton class that would take care of loading and storing the files. But I'm assuming each thor tasks will run on separate processes and cannot share the singleton instance created. How do I proceed with the design for this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

In theory, you could do this using UNIX shared memory and some kind of gem that allows access to those system calls (some are described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41514903/ruby-open-shared-memory-block).

But in practice, it shouldn't matter. Once one of the tasks has run, the contents of the file it read should remain in the operating system's in-memory file cache even after the process exits. When the other tasks open the file, so long as the cache hasn't been evicted in the meantime, they will access the file contents -- or at least some of it -- directly from memory, without the performance hit of reading from disk.

This is one of those situations where, until benchmarks show that a more dramatic solution is needed, trusting in existing caching solutions is easiest and most robust.